# Handle TCP KeepAlive in iOS Background

Tags: ios, tcp

My server is sending some kind of empty string (just one space), most probably it is done by server tcp keepalive, & I can not change server code.

In background mode my iOS applications wakes up for every packet coming into the stream & hence this empty strings makes my application crash with message (15 in 300 secs). Can i control this from iOS side so that it ignores all empty packets??

Comment: Could you please share some code that you are using to send and receive data from server? Or else it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: We are using xmppframework in iOS & Openfire as server. xmppframework uses GCDAsyncSocket internally. As per I understood by reading server code as of now is the tcp keepalive is controlled by OS Kernel & to check connection it usually sends empty packets in sockets.

Comment: My Question here is, that is there anyway to tell iOS not to wakeup my application if the packet is empty string?